# How to ignore a mouse event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a component that is draggable. However, it cannot be dragged if the user drags while the mouse is on the text field. How can I set the Text field so the user can click-drag on that part of the interface?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"  creationComplete="init()" width="210" height="150" styleName="noteStyle" >
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public var testId:int;
        public var buttonNumber:int;
        public function init():void{
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, makeDraggable)
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endDrag)
            this.buttonMode = true;
            this.useHandCursor = true;
        }
        public function saveButtonHandler():void{
            dispatchEvent(new Event  ( "noteClosed"));
        }
        public function cancelButtonHandler():void{
            dispatchEvent(new Event  ( "noteCancelled"));
        }
        public function makeDraggable(e:Event):void{
            //If the target and the current target are the same, then it must be the background, so make it draggable.
            //Stops the text field and buttons from being draggable
            trace("Target= "+e.currentTarget+" "+e.target)
            if(e.currentTarget==e.target){
                this.startDrag();
            }
        }
        public function endDrag(e:Event):void{
            this.stopDrag();
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
    <mx:Text  text="Add a note: Drag to move"   styleName="myriadPro14"   selectable="false"   />
    <mx:Button  id="saveButton" label="Save" x="146" y="120" click="saveButtonHandler()" />
    <mx:Button  id="cancelButton" label="Cancel" x="10" y="120" click="cancelButtonHandler()"  />
    <mx:TextArea id="noteText" width="200" height="80"     horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="-12"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: textField.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, makeDraggable);
textField.buttonMode = true;
textField.useHandCursor = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event listener to the text field as well.

Comment: Instead of adding a listener he should use the `mouseChildren` property as defined on `DisplayObjectContainer`. It disables mouse and user input if set to false.

Comment: @TimLieberman I encountered a similar problem- i had a dynamic text field inside a MovieClip and when I added a Mouse.CLICK event listener to the movie clip, it captured the text field instance instead of the clip. My solution was: textField.mouseEnabled = false, that made the text field ignore mouse events, and apparently pass them on.